# Start another Borderlands playthrough

Tags: borderlands

After I finished Borderlands main story (not DLC) when I exited and restarted the game, it asked me if I want to continue Playthrough 1 or start Playthrough 2.

But what will happen to my character if I start Playthrough 2?

- Do I start the game from the beginning?
- Do I lose my current skills or my equipments with my character?
- Are the enemies tougher (I hope so)?
- If I start Playthrough 2 and haven't finished the DLC in Playtorugh 1 does it matter?

Comment: The playthroughs seem to be the equivalent of Diablo's Normal, Nightmare and Hell difficulty levels.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit**

Well since people are actually reading this, there's a little bit more information on each point.

The answers in order:

- Yes - All quests reset - The game begins just as though you had started at lvl 1 (minus the character selection, so you'll have to do everything over again (including the tutorial!)
- No - You keep everything - This is pretty straightforward, what you have on you at the end of playthrough 1 stays with you.  However, items in playthrough 2 are scaled (see below on scaling).  So you'll find the same named weapons but they will have better stats, so don't just ignore them.
- Yes - Mobs scale to your level -It is expected that after completing your first playthrough you will be around lvl 35 (give or take).  Therefore when you start a new game, the mobs will have 35 added to their level (again give or take a level).  Which is why specific enemies (like Crawmerax for example) have a set level.  If you're looking to do the Secret Armory of General Knoxx, you should be lvl 50ish (about 2.5 playthroughs).
- No - You can go find it in playthrough 2, or you can access playthrough one with your current character (so if you have gained a level in playthrough 2, that level sticks when going back to playthrough 1).  This includes any subsequent playthroughs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Actually this question got me back to playing Borderlands again!