# Options after completing Borderlands

Tags: borderlands

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start another Borderlands playthrough](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4919/start-another-borderlands-playthrough)

I'm about to finish my first playthrough of Borderlands. Apparently I'll be given the choice of restarting the game with the same character (playthrough 2), or continuing on playthrough 1. If I choose to continue, can I start playthrough 2 at any time? How would I do so?

Also, I haven't yet decided whether to get any DLC yet, but if I did I would like to be able to play it straight away. Do you have to be a certain level for any of the DLC? As far as the DLC is concerned, would I be better off in Playthrough 1 or 2?

Comment: As far as DLC, I seem to remember Zombie Island requiring about low 50's level, And General Knoxx closer to 60, otherwise they didn't scale really well if you were a lower level. I may be off on the numbers, hence, just the comment (and it could be because I was terrible and played the game solo)

Comment: LOL Doozer. I probably depends on which class you're playing and how you build them. I played through as Brick, soloing all the DLC from about lvl 40-ish (i think). Playing as Lilith would be harder (i imagine)...

Comment: I read that other question before posting this one, it asks what happens when you start P2, whereas I wanted to know if/how I could start P2 despite continuing with P1. I didn't know I could switch between playthroughs at will, and now I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, playthroughs first. Once you have completed the game once, when you load a character you are given the option of going to Playthrough 1 (the one you just finished) or Playthrough 2 (a new game, same character).

As for the DLC, I got it all with the GOTY edition, and then played it straight through after finishing the base game. You should only need to have finished the game once (depending, of course, on how many side missions etc you have completed).

Answer (score 1):

You can keep using your character to play either playthrough at any time. The advantage to playing playthrough #2 is that you get more challenge, more XP, better guns, and you get to do all the quests again. However, you can still run around in playthrough #1 if you prefer, basically killing everything without much difficulty ***cough***Crawmerax***cough*** and finishing up side quests.

Comment: Isn't Crawmerax still level 61 in playthrough #1?

Comment: Not sure, I just meant that he would _not_ be part of the 'killing everything without much difficulty' list :)